# Action Script 3 Linkage mystery

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a button symbol in the library that has a linkage. when I run my movie, everything works fine. If I go into the properties of that button turn off linkage, then immediatly turn it back on with the same settings, then run the movie. I get;

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Phase02_btn.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Phase02_btn.

Anyone know what's going on, and how to fix it?

JD-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that error in flash is telling you it can't find the Phase02_btn class. So it sounds like you must have changed the linkage name.

Be careful when you unselect and reselect 'export for actionscript', as flash WILL change your linkage name to that of the movieclips name by default.

Comment: Double checked. The linkage name is identical to what I'm using in my code. Still getting the error.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide the .fla file (I have CS5 so I can take any version)? Sometimes flash can act really weird

Comment: Around 1am I discovered that if I changed the symbol from _btn to _mc it all worked fine. Linkage doesn't like button symbols it seems.